# Why the JVM is not able to detect some invalid paths

Tags: java

I want to know why the `JVM` doesn't throw any exception when it is asked to create an invalid path such "`C:invalidPath`".
For example :

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
   File f = new File("C:invalidPath");
   f.mkdir();
}
```

The previous example create a folder named "invalidPath" in the current folder. I think that this is not normal .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the JVM's fault or responsibility.

It is up to the underlying filesystem to convert a path specification (i.e. string) into the actual logical files that the name represents.  The JVM just passes through this string to the filesystem, which determines how to handle it.

So the real question is "why does **NTFS** [assuming that's what you're using] interpret 'C:invalidPath' as creating that file in the current directory?".  And the reason is simply, that's how paths are defined for this filesystem.

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#paths):

> If a file name begins with only a disk designator but not the backslash after the colon, it is interpreted as a relative path to the current directory on the drive with the specified letter. Note that the current directory may or may not be the root directory depending on what it was set to during the most recent "change directory" operation on that disk. Examples of this format are as follows:
>
> - "C:tmp.txt" refers to a file named "tmp.txt" in the current directory on drive C.

Answer (score 8):

The path you have specified is a legal path on Microsoft Windows. It is specified as path relative to the current working directory on the volume C. On Windows, as on DOS before it, each volume has a separate working directory associated with it, and additionally there is the notion of the *current working volume*.